# SQL 2000 TSQL - Creating Pivot Table

Tags: t-sql, linq-to-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2000, crosstab

I am really struggling with figuring out how to convert a MS Access CrossTab query into T-SQL to run on SQL2000 or into Linq-to-SQL.  What I have is a query that looks like this in Access:

[image: Access Cross Tab Query]
And produces this:
[image: Access Cross Tab Query Results]

The query basically groups by ItemID and StoreID and Sums the Qty sold, but with the CrossTab query in Access, I am able to have a unique ItemID for each row, a column for each StoreID, and the total Qty for each StoreID/ItemID combination as the value.

How do you construct this in T-SQL 2000?  I can build a simple select query with grouping, but it gives me the data in three columns, StoreID, ItemID, and Qty.  But what I need is a column for ItemID and a column for every StoreID in the result set

```
SELECT     Trans.TranSID as StoreID, TransDetail.TranItemID as ItemID, SUM(TransDetail.Qty) AS TotalQtyForStore
    FROM         Trans INNER JOIN
                          TransDetail ON Trans.TranID = TransDetail.TranID INNER JOIN
                          Item ON TransDetail.TranItemID = Item.ItemID
    WHERE     (Trans.TranDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2005-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Trans.TranTypeID = 'so' OR
                          Trans.TranTypeID = 'ca') AND (Trans.TranStatus <> 'v') AND (Item.ItemClassID = 'RHM')
    GROUP BY Trans.TranSID, TransDetail.TranItemID
```

Which produces this:

[image]

But what I really need to do is transform this data so that the StoreID values become columns, like the Access CrossTab query above.

Comment: I wouldn't typically do this in the SQL, I'd perform the cross tab in whatever reporting tool I was using.  It's relatively simple using reporting services for example.

Comment: I agree.  It just drives me nuts that something like this takes 2 seconds in Access but I can't figure it out in T-SQL or Linq-to-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with dynamic SQL, since you probably don't know all of the store (TranSID) values in advance. This stored procedure takes start/end date as parameters, and generates a cross-tab. You can probably parameterize some of the other things as well, such as TranStatus and ItemClassID, but it wasn't clear if those are fixed or variable elements in your query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CrossTabByItem
  @StartDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate   DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SET @EndDate = COALESCE(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate), GETDATE());

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); SET @sql = N'';

  SELECT @sql = @sql + ',
    [' + TranSID + '] = SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranSID = ''' 
    + TranSID + ''' THEN td.Qty ELSE 0 END)' FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT TranSID FROM dbo.Trans
      WHERE TranDate >= @StartDate AND TranDate < @EndDate
    ) AS x ORDER BY TranSID;

    SET @sql = N'SELECT ItemID = td.TranItemID' + @sql + '
      FROM dbo.Trans AS t
      INNER JOIN dbo.TransDetail AS td
       ON t.TranID = td.TranID
      INNER JOIN dbo.Item AS i
       ON td.TranItemID = i.ItemID
      WHERE t.TranDate >= @StartDate
      AND t.TranDate < @EndDate
      AND t.TranTypeID IN (''so'',''ca'')
      AND t.TranStatus <> ''v''
      AND i.ItemClassID = ''RHM''
      GROUP BY td.TranItemID;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
      N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME', 
      @StartDate, @EndDate;
END
GO
```

So you can call it like this, to get everything from January 1st, 2005 until right now:

```
EXEC dbo.CrossTabByItem @StartDate = '20050101';
```

Or like this, to get just January of 2005:

```
EXEC dbo.CrossTabByItem @StartDate = '20050101', @EndDate = '20050131';
```

Comment: I created the stored procedure and ran it as is, but I get an error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'"

Comment: Sorry, all your unnecessary brackets led to a careless typo on my part. Please try now.

Comment: Bam!  That got it.  I am stunned and humbled.  I will parameterize the ClassID and this will be good to go.  Thanks a million!!!

Comment: Aaron, you helped me tremendously with this a while back and it has been working great in production, but I need to tweak it a little and I'm having hard time getting it to work.  Any chance you could look at it again?

Comment: Here's a link to the new question I posted.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862086/trouble-with-dynamic-t-sql-iif-statement)