# Trouble with Dynamic T-SQL IIF Statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, iif

This code works fine and does exactly what I want, which is to sum the Qty * Price for each instance of the dynamic query.

[image: Working Code]

But when I add an IIF statement it breaks.  What I am trying to do is the same thing as above but when the transaction type is 'CO' set the sum to a negative amount.

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  What do you mean breaks? Do you get an error?

Comment: SQL 2012 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'THE'.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near 'THE'`? If it's a real message there's probably a typo in preceding `THEN`.

Comment: Hard to figure out what it could be, if I remove IIF statement only everything works fine.  Nothing else changes.

Comment: @GaryGerson my suggestion would be to write it not in the dynamic sql then convert it.

Comment: ACtually, I can leave the IIF statement in there and as long as I don't have the Cast(td.Price as money) in there it's fine.

Comment: @GaryGerson what's the length of `@sql` in the end of it all? Maybe it gets truncated at 4000 characters, because it's `NVARCHAR(4000)`?

Comment: you might be on to something.  I'll check that.  There are 25 iterations of the dynamic script and I bet that is the issue.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  The dynamic script is roughly 3800 characters and the whole thing goes over 4000.  Wonder what I can change it to?

Comment: Does `NVARCHAR(max)` work for local variables? If it does, then that's it.

Comment: @GaryGerson change your code to `declare @sql nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Set sql to NVARCHAR(max) and now it works.  Thanks Anton.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Post that as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: you guys beat me to it.  Problem solved!  Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the `NVARCHAR(4000)` type of `@sql`, limiting its length to 4000 characters: the query got truncated at some random place after adding another long chunk to it.

`DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)` solves the problem, allowing a dynamic query of any size below 2GB.